# How to add new online ressources to RAD Studio help system

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Delphi for a while uses the `MS Help V2.x` help system. It provides the program `h2reg.exe` to add additional context sensitive help files, such as ones for third party components.

If `MS document explorer`, the program used to display help, cannot find a certain help page locally, it searches through a bunch of online ressources.

What I need now is the ability to add new online sources. We have a large framework for delphi with an extensive online documentation that is version controlled. If possible we would love if we had not to generate offline .Hx?-files.

Is there a way to accomplish this? I searched the [helpware group knowledge base](http://kb.helpwaregroup.com) and could not find anything on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking to somebody formerly on the development team of `MS Document Explorer` and now `r2reg`, this is not possible. And since MS moved on from MS Help 2 and now uses `MS Help Viewer`, there will not be any further development to allow for this.